# Switch View Controller From TableViewCell Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

I would like to present a new ViewController when user clicks element in tableviewcell.  The standard code for launching a VC, however, does not work from a tableview cell or even in a helper class because neither a TVC nor a helper class can present a view controller.

Here is the code in a helper class.  Whether placed in the helperclass or the tableview cell, it doesn't have a present method to launch a VC.

```
class launchVC {
 func launchVCNamed(identifier: String) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contactDetail")
//FOLLOWING LINE HAS ERROR NO SUCH MEMBER (present)
    self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }
```

How can I modify this to launch a VC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you should use delegate pattern, or closure to pass a block from cell back to view controller. I prefer using closures to delegates so I'll give such example:

```
class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {
    var actionBlock = { }

    func someActionOccured() { // some action like button tap in cell occured
        actionBlock()
    }
}
```

And in `cellForRow` in view controller you need to assign the closure

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SomeCell // replace cell identifier with whatever your identifier is
    cell.actionBlock = { [unowned self] in 
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contactDetail")
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a delegate to your cell and assign it to the presentingVC. See below.

**Using Delegation**

Create a CustomCell that inherits from UITableViewCell.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var cellDelegate : CustomCellDelegate = nil

    @IBAction func elementTapped() {
        cellDelegate?.launchVC()
    }
}
```

**Custom Cell Delegate**

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func launchVC()
}
```

**MainViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewControllerDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? CustomCell {

            // important
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

**Extend ViewController to implement the protocol**

```
extension ViewContrller: CustomCellDelegate {
    func launchVC() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, if you're trying to present a VC from a TableViewCell, @olejnjak has the correct implementation.